# Is it possible to disable XSLT compilation of XSLT stylesheets edited in Visual Studio's XML editor?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, visual-studio-2017

The editing of XSLT documents in Visual Studio is XSD schema-based (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/schema-cache) and by default the schema used (`xslt.xsd`) supports XSLT 1.0.

However, since 1999 when XSLT 1.0 became a W3C recommendation the XSLT world has progressed to XSLT 2.0 in 2007 and finally to XSLT 3.0 in 2017. And with the .NET version of [Saxon 9.8 HE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/) and XmlPrime there are .NET implementations of those standards, so it is desirable to those developing .NET applications using newer versions of XSLT than the default XSLT 1.0 schema supports, to be able to use the XML editor in Visual Studio to edit XSLT 2 or 3 stylesheets.

I have managed to get intellisense for XSLT 2 or 3 by putting an edited copy of the schema http://www.w3.org/2007/schema-for-xslt20.xsd respectively https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/schema-for-xslt30.xsd into the schema cache directory, however what then is happening is that I write XSLT 2 or 3 using the intellisense in the editor [while in the background it compiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/editing-xslt-style-sheets) the XSLT code with XslCompiledTransform according to XSLT 1 rules and obviously gives me a lot of errors that are not relevant and misleading when I want to author XSLT 2 or 3.

So does anyone know whether there is a setting or API to disable the background compilation of XSLT in the XML editor?